# I want that email header part does not contain via link

Tags: php

when a user submits Contact Us form on our site and the info comes to us the email header contains from: abc@gmail.com via 218208-db2.christiandatingforfree.com. We dont want via 218208-db2.christiandatingforfree.com in the header part. Any suggestions...

Comment: Without giving us more information about how you are sending the email, it's very hard for us to answer this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask explains how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't something you can control. Gmail does it for the sake of security, otherwise you could send an email with the from field as `support@gmail.com`